# APBS segment fault on pymol 1.8.x

Tags: pymol

I have been trying to run APBS on pymol but it always get terminated abruptly with the following error:

```
In show error 1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When select "set grid", the following popups

```
GENERATING PQR FILE via PDB2PQR
Erasing contents of /home/srinivasanh/pymol/pymol-generated.pdb in order to generate new PDB file
Erasing contents of /home/srinivasanh/pymol/pymol-generated.pdb in order to clean it up
TESTING
DONE TESTING
args are now converted to string:  /usr/local/packages/pdb2pqr-src-2.1.0/pdb2pqr.py --ff=AMBER /home/srinivasanh/pymol/pymol-generated.pdb /home/srinivasanh/pymol/pymol-generated.pqr

--------------------------
PDB2PQR - a Python-based structural conversion utility
--------------------------
Please cite your use of PDB2PQR as:
  Dolinsky TJ, Nielsen JE, McCammon JA, Baker NA.
  PDB2PQR: an automated pipeline for the setup, execution,
  and analysis of Poisson-Boltzmann electrostatics calculations.
  Nucleic Acids Research 32 W665-W667 (2004).


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/packages/pdb2pqr-src-2.1.0/pdb2pqr.py", line 62, in <module>
    mainCommand(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/packages/pdb2pqr-src-2.1.0/main.py", line 740, in mainCommand
    include_old_header = options.include_header)
  File "/usr/local/packages/pdb2pqr-src-2.1.0/main.py", line 281, in runPDB2PQR
    myProtein = Protein(pdblist, myDefinition)
  File "/usr/local/packages/pdb2pqr-src-2.1.0/src/protein.py", line 121, in __init__
    myResidue = self.createResidue(residue, previousAtom.resName)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'resName'

PDB2PQR's mainCommand returned 1
In show error 2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have compiled pymol 1.8.2 manually then added Pymol-script-repo through pymolwiki guide which installs APBS 1.4.1 and APBS Tools 2.1.
[ABPS pymolwiki guide](http://pymolwiki.org/index.php/APBS)

Running system

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

And the following dependencies are installed

```
sudo apt-get install python python-dev python-pmw python-numpy freeglut3-dev libglew-dev libpng12-dev libfreetype6-dev build-essential libxml++2.6-dev build-essential
```

GPU Drivers

```
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 4.304...   Driver Version: 304.131        |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                     | Bus-Id        Disp.  | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap| Memory-Usage         | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTS 250          | 0000:03:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
|  4%   47C  N/A     N/A /  N/A |  39%  402MB / 1023MB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0            Not Supported                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have been looking around for alternatives, have also tried ubuntu repository installation of pymol 1.7.0.0.

Can anyone give me some advise?
Thank you~